# VoiceOver doesn't read the text inside window.alert in Chrome

Tags: javascript, accessibility, alert

The following code snippet shows a `window.alert` if the user is using IE11 or lower versions:

```
function isIE() {
  // If IE11 or bellow return true
  return window.navigator.userAgent.match(/(MSIE|Trident)/);
}

if (!isIE()) {
  window.alert("Your browser is outdated!");
}
```

It works, however, the window.alert should be accessible so that the screen reader should read the text inside the `window.alert`, which is "Your browser is outdated!".

I'm testing this on a MacBook with Apple VoiceOver.

It works in FireFox and the VoiceOver reads the text inside the window.alert.

But if I run the exact same test in Chrome, the VoiceOver doesn't read the text inside the `window.alert`.

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

As alternative to it, you can use `aria-live` regions.

MDN: (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions).

DEMO: 
(https://support.freedomscientific.com/Training/Surfs-Up/AriaLiveRegions.htm).

Comment: Unfortunately, VoiceOver and Chrome or FF won't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, VoiceOver and Chrome, similar to firefox have a problem with reading alerts. I try to resolve them in many ways, bat none of one wont to work... Here are some examples:

[Few ideas, working mostly with Windows OS (FF, CH, IE, Edge) NVDA but MacOS say by when try to read VoiceOver and FF or Chrome...](https://github.com/marekz/accesibility)

This works correctly, but here I use focus(), so the user who uses the screen reader will lost his focus. Because of this it is completely wrong way...
[Not recommended method with focus()](https://github.com/marekz/accesibility/blob/master/index_7.html)

The correct way is [here](https://github.com/marekz/accesibility/blob/master/index_3.html), but unfortunately didn't work with CHROME and FF when screen reader VoiceOver read content added to alert field

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Assertive test 3</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p>Click submit button to see message</p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit">
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="errors" aria-live="assertive">
            <div id="divBlok" role="alert">
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            var elementX = document.getElementById("divBlok");
            var alertText = document.createTextNode("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.");
            $("#button").click(function (e) {
                elementX.appendChild(alertText);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```